# AuthType Digest Realm Password White Space Issue

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, password

I have an issue where I am trying to set a test directory to authenticate using the AuthType Digest. I have been able to successfully complete this but only when the AuthName of .htaccess is one string entry.

**Example .htaccess:**

```
Options +Indexes 

AuthName "Gordon" 
AuthType Digest
AuthDigestDomain /
AuthDigestProvider file
AuthUserFile C:/xampp/htdocs/HTAccessible/test/htdigest/.htpasswd

<Limit GET POST PUT> 
require valid-user 
</Limit>
```

**Example .htpasswd**

```
go_admin:'Gordon':0acefe7c35fab863f9a03f2e3f88f168qNG0
```

---

If I change the Realm in .htpasswd and .htaccess AuthName to "Gordon and" ..I get this error (from Apache logs/error.log)

```
[Sat Aug 24 15:14:27.864534 2013] [auth_digest:error] [pid 6840:tid 1716] [client 127.0.0.1:49646] AH01790: user `go_admin' in realm `Gordon and' not found: /HTAccessible/test/htdigest/
```

I have tried encasing the Realm in single and double quotes marks to no avail, currently editing using Notepad++ but have also tried creating via the ht_digest.exe tool ...still no dice.

I have also looked on the  [Apache AuthType and ht_digest docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) but maybe its not the right section as I can't seem to find any information on containing whitespaced realms.

Any pointers or advice would be appreciated, thanks.